# How to connect Zoho CRM to Qlik Sense?

Tags: rest, crm, qliksense, zoho

How can one establish a connection between Zoho CRM and Qlik Sense by utilizing the REST connector that is made available by Qlik Sense? Are there specific steps or guidelines to follow in order to successfully integrate the two platforms using this method?

Answer (score 0):

The process wouldn't be any different than connecting to any other OAuth2 REST service.

Step 1 would be to set up authentication. I suggest using a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to get the initial access and refresh tokens.

- When you [register a client](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v5/register-client.html), you would need to choose the **Self Client** option.
- If the `Authorized redirect URIs` value is required, then it should be whatever Postman has you use, usually something like `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback`.
- After you create the client, follow the instructions for using **Self Client** method for getting the grant token (see [these docs](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v5/auth-request.html#self-client)).
- Use Postman to use your grant token to get back the initial access and refresh tokens (see [this page](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v5/access-refresh.html)). This would be to quickly validate the process and make sure you are getting it working.
- Once you get it working in Postman, you can now set up a new REST connection in Qlik Sense, you would set it up with those same settings as in your Postman test.
- If your new REST connection works, save it and then modify the `LIB CONNECT TO` line in this script. Then add that script to a new section in the Data Load Editor and move that section to be just below the **Main** section:

.

```
    // ==== GET NEW TOKEN ====
    
SUB GetGraphToken
    LIB CONNECT TO 'ZOHO CRM API - AUTH';
    RestConnectorMasterTable:
    SQL SELECT 
        "token_type",
        "expires_in",
        "ext_expires_in",
        "access_token"
    FROM JSON (wrap on) "root";

    [GraphToken]:
    LOAD
        Now() as [token_acquired_ts],
        [token_type],
        [expires_in],
        [ext_expires_in],
        [access_token]
    RESIDENT RestConnectorMasterTable;
    DROP TABLE RestConnectorMasterTable;
    
    Store [GraphToken] into 'lib://SomeFolder/GraphToken.qvd'(QVD);
    Let vToken = peek('access_token', 0, 'GraphToken');
    Drop Table GraphToken;
END SUB

//  ==== TOKEN CHECK ====

SUB TokenCheck
    Let vNow = Now();
    Let vQVD_ts = Coalesce(timestamp#( QvdCreateTime('lib://SomeFolder/GraphToken.qvd')  + (60/60/24) - ((60/60/24/60/60)*5) ), 0);
    Let vCompare = timestamp('$(vNow)') > timestamp('$(vQVD_ts)');
    
    IF timestamp(Now()) > timestamp(Coalesce( QvdCreateTime('lib://SomeFolder/GraphToken.qvd')  + (60/60/24) - ((60/60/24/60/60)*5), 0) ) THEN
        Trace #### Graph token expired...getting new token now.;
        CALL GetGraphToken
    ELSE
        Trace #### Graph token still good.;
        GraphToken: LOAD [access_token] FROM 'lib://SomeFolder/GraphToken.qvd'(QVD);
        Let vToken = peek('access_token', 0, 'GraphToken');
        Drop Table GraphToken;
    END IF
END SUB
```

- Create another new REST connection for making either GET or POST calls to the ZOHO API (just depends on what APIs you're going to be querying from).
- After you play around with that connection a bit to generate the load scripts you'll need for your queries, just reuse that same connection by utilizing the [`WITH CONNECTION ()` modifier](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/REST_Connector_help/Content/Connectors_REST/Load-REST-data/Load-data.htm#anchor-5).
- Before any of the queries you run in the load script against those ZOHO APIs, simply use `CALL TokenCheck` to make sure you have an up-to-date access token.